# In which order are event listeners added to the call stack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, onscrolllistener

I am writing a scroll synchronization module in js, and am encountering some very unexpected behavior with how scroll events are firing. Starting with the code:

```
const attach = (element) => {
  // synchronizedElements is in scope because of closures
  const onScrollListener = () => {

    // first detach all other listeners
    synchronizedElements.current.forEach((listener, el) => 
      if(el !== element) el.removeEventListener('scroll', listener)
    );
    

    // synchronize all of the other elements with the leader
    syncFollowers({leader: element, synchronizedElements});

    // then re-attach all of the other listeners
    synchronizedElements.current.forEach((listener, el) => 
      if(el !== element) el.addEventListener('scroll', listener)
    );
  }
  synchronizedElements.current.add(element, onScrollListener);
  element.addEventListener('scroll', synchronizedElements);
}
```

With this, I would expect the first element to be scrolled to have its listener invoked. It would assume the role of leader and remove all of the other elements; (followers) so it can move their scroll positions *without them firing their onScrollListeners in response*. And then reattach the listeners so they can be leaders again. This is critical so the followers don't also try to do the exact same thing.

Instead, what happens is that the followers' listeners all also get invoked immediately after the leader's is done. All I'd like to do is bypass the non-leaders' scroll events while the leader is scrolling.

I'm wondering if the `removeEventListener` + `addEventListener` are queued and not actually executed until this entire function completes, thus the followers still have their listeners attached when the leader moves them. Any thoughts?

Comment: mmmm... perhaps you have already thought the following or not, i just will split it out: do you know that events in browsers have two phases: capture (from bigger component into specific) and bubble (from specicif into bigger), try to imaginate that your click goes beyond the screen traversing element in the same hierchieal order they are placed. On any listener you have the change to stop chain, so i guest if you stop the capture phase, like `event.stopProgration()` in the bigger one (leader)  is enought.

Comment: I don't believe the on scroll event bubbles @Victor

Comment: What does `syncFollowers` do exactly? If it does scroll these elements, then new events may fire (later). Also what is  `synchronizedElements.current`? Its forEach's signature seems weird.

Comment: It does scroll them, so the goal was to remove the event listeners while this occurs. Is there any non-hacky way around having them spawn their respective events? `synchronizedElements` is a react reference, which is a stable wrapper "box" object with a mutable current property.

Comment: oh, and the `current` field is set to a map

Comment: Wait the next painting frame before releasing a flag: in the handler `if(handling){return;}else{handling = true;requestAnimationFrame(()=>requestAninationFrame(()=>handling=false;))`. Maybe a single rAF is enough, as I believe the new events should get handled in the same frame, but better be safe. Also, I'm on a phone, so I can't test myself.

Comment: Thank you, i'll test it out

Comment: could you not simply have a leader flag and conditional in the listener callback to check for leader/follower status? no listener juggling.

Comment: That's similar to what i've got, just accomplished a different way. It's like when the other elements' listeners are invoked, the leader has already been recalled (if i put both election and recall within the scope of the listener). I'm testing this with a short debounce right now to see if i can get it to pass all of the follower listeners before recalling.